# How can I linearize this inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Is there a way to linearize this inequality? maybe by separing this inequality into three?
I have an optimization model where one of the restrictions is the following, which makes the model a non-linear model. 
$$|x_1| + |x_2| + |x_3| \leq 2$$

Comment: What do you mean by linearise? You could have $x_k \le a_k, -x_k \le a_k, a_1+a_2+a_3 \le 2$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. How could I define a in an optimization model? Don't know if you read the next text I wrote but that inequality is a restriction from an optimization model I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but it not unusual to convert an optimisation problem into an equivalent problem with additional variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by linearize but I will interpret this to mean write the constraint as a linear inequality so the optimization problem you're solving can be seen as a linear program.

Introduce the variables $x_i^+,x_i^-$ where $x_i^+ = max(x_i,0)$, $x_i^- = max(-x_i,0)$. Then $x_i = x_i^+ - x_i^-$ and the given constraint becomes

$x_1^+ + x_1^- + x_2^+ + x_2^- + x_3^+ + x_3^- \leq 2$

Now you can work entirely in the $x_i^+,x_i^-$ coordinates and then use $x_i = x_i^+ - x_i^-$ once you are done your optimization to find the values of your original variables.